# Show boxes underneath each other using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Code:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.box {
    width:20%;
    min-width:350px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px 25px 0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

I want maximum 4 boxes to display across the page, in this example I have 7 so 4 then 3 below. How can I make the 3 below display underneath the first 3 on the top row but still make the 4 across display in the centre of the `container` div?

http://jsfiddle.net/UJD8L/1/

Comment: i want the boxes to display in the centre of the container div but not get any smaller than 350px so they then display under each other as the screen gets smaller

Answer (score 2):

Setting a `min-width` may conflict with your goal of having each block take up 20% or 1/4 of the container. You can ensure the floating effect you're after by doing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UJD8L/3/

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.box {
    width:20%;
    /* min-width:350px; */
    float:left;
    margin:10px 25px 0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

---

**Update:**

Setting the blocks to `display: inline-block` rather than `inline` and removing the float property centers the blocks in the layout and allows them to stack:

http://jsfiddle.net/UJD8L/4/

```
.box {
    /* width:20%; */
    min-width:350px;
    /* float:left; */
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px 25px 0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    /* display:inline; */
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: i want a min-width so as the screen is smaller it will put the boxes underneath each other

Comment: yeah but i also want the boxes to display in the centre of the container div

Comment: as the container is 100% wide and the boxes add up to 20% wide with a 25px right margin so there is space on the left and right of the page

Comment: see update; note that setting `width: 100%` on the `.container` div has no effect; divs fill 100% of their container unless you specify otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to manipulate container height and add these overflow property. So change your **.container** css;

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height: 230px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

**Edit:** Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UJD8L/9/) link...